# Getting Proxy 407 Error While Accessing In Python requests

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, proxy, python-requests

I have the below code to access the website using a proxy using the python request module. I'm running it on my windows machine and it works fine. But I'm trying to do  something in a linux server and it fails, but I can telnet the proxy server from Linux machine without any issues.

```
import requests
proxies = {'http': '192.168.10.22:80'}
URL = 'https://accesscontrol.windows.net/secret-code'
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
request.post(URL, header=header, proxies=proxies)
'''
Using the above code, I can access proxy without any issue, but If I use the code in Linux server, I'm getting the below error.

requets.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host=****, port=***) Max retries exceeded with URL: *** (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel Connection failed: 407 proxy Authentication Required')))

Both the Linux and Windows boxes I'm accessing in the corporate network. I'm not sure, why windows can authenticate even if I didn't pass username and password. But its not working, not sure did windows passing credential using single sign on or python recognized my username and password and authenticating it.

Please share some suggestion to overcome this issue, Thank You!!
```

Comment: Just as a test, can you add your Windows username and password in proxies and test in Linux ?

Comment: @Philippe already tried both basic authentication and digest authentication but still getting the same error.

Comment: is there any way I can collect the complete request going through the windows machine from `request.get`? so that I can check the same request is requested through the linux system, If any difference I can correct it, please suggest.

Comment: Try https://www.telerik.com/fiddler